# Caesar code in C extra letter for result

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

void caesar(char bemenet[], char eredmeny[], int n){ 
int i = 0; 
    for(i = 0; bemenet[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
        if(bemenet[i] == 'z') { 
            eredmeny[i] = 'a'; 
            eredmeny[i] += n-1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            eredmeny[i] += n; 
        } 
    } 
    eredmeny[i] = '\0'; 
}

int main(){
char tomb1[]="caesarkodolas";
char tomb2[]="";

caesar(tomb1,tomb2,1);

printf("%s \n",tomb2);

return 0;
}
```

My out for the "eredmeny" (result) this:
"dbftbslpepmb" but tomb2=> ☺dbftbslpepmb it's not OK.. cause I have an extra char |☺|..

Comment: The output array is too small, so this is blatant undefined behaviour.

Comment: This approach is broken - it is not going to work for `n` above `1`. Try your modified code with `caesar(tomb1,tomb2,10);` [to see some garbage output](http://ideone.com/cyVmK0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should have `tomb2` big enough to store result.

For example, as mentioned above

```
char tomb2[255] = {0};
```

Also you have error here

```
else 
{
    eredmeny[i] += n; 
}
```

You have to assign valid ASCII value to `eredmeny[i]` so change this string to

`eredmeny[i] += bemenet[i] + n`

Also it usually bad practice to pass a pointer on array without passing its size. Easy to get buffer overflow.

Comment: Since you accepted this answer, please look at @dasblinkenlight 's advice how to write bulletproof version of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate enough memory for the second parameter, and change this line

```
eredmeny[i] += n;
```

to this:

```
eredmeny[i] = bemenet[i] + n;
```

Note that this is *not* a bulletproof implementation of [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher): it would work for `n==1`, but it will break for larger `n`.

You need to think of a different way of implementing the "wrap-around": rather than testing for `'z'` and replacing it with `'a'`, compute the new position of a letter modulo 26, and then add `a` to it:

```
void caesar(char bemenet[], char eredmeny[], int n){ 
    int i;
    for(i = 0; bemenet[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // Compute the position of the replacement letter
        int pos = (bemenet[i] - 'a' + n) % 26;
        // Place the letter into the output.
        eredmeny[i] = 'a' + pos; 
    } 
    eredmeny[i] = '\0'; 
}
```

[demo.](http://ideone.com/hd43eH)

Answer (score 0):

you're not doing the maths right.

if you are using just lower case letters then you need to add `n`, but then many letters will be "after" z, so you need to start again at a.

you want something more like this:

```
for(i = 0; bemenet[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
    int encrypted = bemenet[i] + n;
    if (encrypted > 'z') encrypted = encrypted - 'z' + 'a';
    eredmeny[i] = (char)encrypted;
}
```

(and also fix the output array size as described in other answers here).